# Expansion of $b^{(x+a)^{-n}}$ where $0 \le b \le 1$

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, exponential-sum

The expansion of the negative binomial series is given below.

$$
(x+a)^{-n} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix}n + k - 1\\k\end{pmatrix} x^ka^{-n-k}
$$
when $|x| < a$.

What would be the expansion of $b^{(x+a)^{-n}}$ where $0 \le b \le 1$?

Comment: Nothing short and nice. E.g. the command of Mathematica `Series[x^(x + a)^-n, {x, 0, 3}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  b > 0 && b < 1 && n \[Element] PositiveIntegers && a > 0]` performs $x^{a^{-n}} \left(1-a^{-n-1} n \log (x) x+\frac{1}{2} a^{-2 n-2} n \log (x) \left(n a^n+a^n+n \log (x)\right) x^2-\frac{1}{6} \left(a^{-3 n-3} n \log (x) \left(3 n^2 \log (x) a^n+3 n \log (x) a^n+n^2 a^{2 n}+3 n a^{2 n}+2 a^{2 n}+n^2 \log ^2(x)\right)\right) x^3+O\left(x^4\right)\right)..$